# GBoard app: Initializing of voice-to-text takes forever

Tags: google, voice-recognition, gboard, google-voice

I use GBoard on my Poco X3 and the keyboard sporadically takes forever to initialize when using Voice Typing. Sometimes it's fast, sometimes it isnt. Sometimes it shows "initializing" and than aborts - sometimes it goes over into speech-recognition mode. Very unreliable :(

Not sure why... Occurs on Wifi, as well as on mobile data connection. Havent found a way to reproduce it reliably.

Any ideas why?
Latest updates installed. Cache already cleared.
Different things tried, nothing yet worked :(

Thanks!

Comment: In  keyboard settings, enable "faster voice typing" //Is the keyboard language set to the phone language

Comment: @beeshyams Unfortunately Im in germany, hence this option is not even available, probably US-only :(

Comment: Maybe it's waiting for the background noise level to decrease before it activates its listen mode???